# Is it possible to do live-stream with MS Bot Framework within VideoCard or anything?

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, http-live-streaming

I am just looking some answers to do live streaming with MS Bot. But could not find any good and valid source to have answer.

Is is possible to do live-streaming with MS Bot in a both way. My BOT should watch a live-stream and also return a live-stream?

Comment: What channel are you using?Currently, we do not have any feature within video card to support this.

Comment: @ranusharao WebChat for example, it would be very nice to have streaming webcam into Bot framework and vice versa. 
If VideoCard will be able to stream from any source over Bot Framework, Bot Framework can learn and respond. I guess, I have to wait :)

Comment: @ranusharao there is a feature like this on the roadmap?